# Writing raw data to a file

Tags: c, file, null-terminated, raw-data

I have an `uint8_t` array of raw data that I want to write to a file (I have it's length)

The problem is that because I'm dealing with raw data there might be a `0x00` (aka null terminator) somewhere, meaning `fputs` is not reliable, the obvious alternative is to have a loop to use `fputc()` but is there a way i can do it without that?

Is there say a function that takes a pointer and a size and writes that amount of data from the pointer's location to the file?

Comment: Take a look at the `mmap(2)` interface.

Comment: @bnaecker mmap looks interesting but does it work for both linux and windows?

Comment: Just open the output file using `fopen` and indicate binary mode. Then use `fwrite`. Should be available on both Windows and Linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to the problem with null-character, there is problem reading binary data when file is opened in text mode (for example `fgets` stops when it encounters new line or `0x0A` and `0x1A` character in Windows)

Open the file in binary mode instead, and use `fread`/`fwrite`

```
FILE *fout = fopen("test.bin", "wb");
```

And use `fwrite` and `fread`

[Reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fwrite)

Answer (score 1):

`fread` and `fwrite` are your friends.

```
uint8_t TheData[NUMBER_OF_ARRAY_ITEMS] = {0};
// ... Transformations to your data ...

// Persist the data
FILE *fHandleOutput = fopen("test.bin", "wb");
if(!fHandleOutput){
   printf("Error: Output file handle was NULL!\n");
   return;
}
// SIGNATURE: fwrite(const void *restrict ptr, size_t size, size_t nitems, FILE *restrict stream);
fwrite(TheData, sizeof(TheData[0]), NUMBER_OF_ARRAY_ITEMS, fHandleOutput);
fflush(fHandleOutput); // Ensure changes get written to disk before we close
fclose(fHandleOutput);
fHandleOutput = NULL;


// Read the data
// Incoming data buffer
uint8_t TheData[NUMBER_OF_ARRAY_ITEMS] = {0};
// Attempt file open for binary mode
FILE *fHandleInput = fopen("test.bin", "rb");
if(!fHandleInput){
   printf("Error: Input file handle was NULL!\n");
   return;
}
// SIGNATURE: fread(void *restrict ptr, size_t size, size_t nitems, FILE *restrict stream);
size_t iRead = fread(TheData, sizeof(TheData[0]), NUMBER_OF_ARRAY_ITEMS, fHandleInput);

fclose(fHandleInput);
fHandleInput = NULL;
```

It's worth noting that the return value of `fread` can be used to detect End-of-File (EOF) and I/O errors. If `iRead < NUMBER_OF_ARRAY_ITEMS`, then either an error occurred, or there were only `iRead`-number of `sizeof(TheData[0])`-byte segments between the filepointer's position and the EOF. (`feof(...)` or `ferror(...)` can be used to determine the cause of a low item read count.)